# Order posts (across the whole site) by metadata date

Tags: functions, query, archives

My custom 'Home' page is set to sort my custom posts via the custom date field with this (updated to be custom named) code in functions.php:

```
// sort order for home page
add_action('wp', 'wwgo_check_page');
function wwgo_check_page () {
if (is_page()) {
    add_filter('get_previous_post_sort', 'sort_it');
    add_filter('get_next_post_sort', 'sort_it');
    add_filter('posts_orderby', 'sort_it' );
    add_filter('posts_join', 'join_it' );
    add_filter('posts_where', 'where_it' );

    function sort_it () {
        global $wpdb;

        return " $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value ASC ";
    }

    function join_it( $join ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $join .= " LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id) ";

      return $join;
    }

    function where_it( $where ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $where .= "AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'deadline' ";

      return $where;
    }
}



}
```

Which is dandy and simple. Now. I want this to work across the whole site. I want posts on archive pages, categories etc to be sorted first by the custom date field.

Any ideas?

I have tried changing the '`if`' to `is_archive()` but that had no effect. I tried `<! is_single()>` too.

*I'm sure it should be something simple. But I'm new to php and thus clueless.*

Here is the [site](http://lit.wyli.co.uk), where you can see the home page is nicely sorted, but if you click 'poetry' (the only one with a few posts), sorting doesn't work.

Any suggestions will be met with much joy.

Thank You Kindly.

Comment: You should prefix all your function with for eg. `josh_` to avoid naming colisions.

Comment: Do you mean that as good practice or to solve this? I tried copying the code in again for 'is_archive' and it did let me call the function again, but sorting didn't work...

Comment: Yes it's good practice. Plus: You shouldn't wrap functions in functions.

Comment: cool, cool (i just copied the code from a website, tbh. I'm new to php & wordpress). Any advance on how to get this to work across the site? I have it working with more custom pages and the same function set to (is_page()) but still this does nothing for my archive pages. I have no clue how to fix them...

Comment: Please go first and update your code to what it looks now.

Comment: Okay, updated. At the moment I have it set to 'is_page()' and I am getting round the problem by making pages for each category. But this doesn't work for tags and is laborious. Also it would be good to know the real way it should be done too. Learning is learning :) Thanks Kaiser!

Comment: n/p. First take a look at the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) to see what `is_archive()` can do for you. Second: don't define functions inside functions. Just call them if you need them in another function.

Comment: Instead of putting functions in functions, try using a class instead.

Comment: i tried is_archive() previously and it had no effect...

Comment: @manny I'm pretty new to php and not entirely sure what you mean. can you clarify or provide an example, please?

Comment: Am I really supposed to ask back on this when it isn't really the same question? Seems odd... I could add my new question to this, but then it get's long and off point, no? Or am I supposed to just edit this question completely?

Comment: I'd ask a new question

Comment: Okay, i did: (it's here:http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21514/make-loop-relative-to-todays-date-for-year-round-posts). But was told to come back to this post. Not sure why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `query_vars` or [request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request) filter to add `orderby` if `orderby` is not presented in the query string

Comment: +1 for `request` filter suggestion

Comment: @josh also check out this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21378/2110 to see how to test for `is_archive()` and alike so early in the process.

Comment: request filter was indeed, a good shout.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use query_posts()?

```
<?php
query_posts('meta_key=key_name&orderby=key_name&sort=ASC');
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

endwhile; else:

endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

You can also alter the query using pre_get_posts hook as well and do your conditional sorting there with is_archive(), is_page() etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at your [other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21514/make-loop-relative-to-todays-date-for-year-round-posts) too.

If you wish to sort by the date meta-value they must naturally be in the same format - I'm guessing it's PHP's date('m-y') format as you specified in your code there?

If that's the case, you may find that if you change your `meta_value` in that code to `meta_value_num` you get a better result?

Not sure this will work, but might be worth a try.