# Alternative to query_posts for main loop?

Tags: query-posts, codex, documentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use WP_query(), query_posts() and pre_get_posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts)

I just noticed today that [the documentation for query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) mentions some "disadvantages" of using query_posts for altering the main Loop, notably: 'causes additional SQL queries'.

This seems to imply that there's another way / a better way. Obviously there's get_posts() and WP_Query for secondary loops, but I don't see them as addressing the "disadvantages" listed in the Codex documentation.

I can see that by waiting until you're in the template to run query_posts, WordPress has already run a query once and this is now a second query that clobbers the first one (the first one being basically ignored). This definitely DOES sound inefficient (though perhaps not a big deal, who knows?)

My question is: is there an alternative to query_posts that does NOT add "additional SQL queries" or is the Codex documentation simply deceiving?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When I added the drawbacks to the Codex, I was mainly thinking of using the 'request' filter as an alternative to query_posts().

That filter is only run for the main query, so that solves the problem with 'pre_get_posts', which fires for every query.

The downside is that you don't have access to query flags like is_single() etc.

Here's one way you could get access to them, without actually doing the SQL queries:

```
function alter_the_query( $request ) {
    $dummy_query = new WP_Query();  // the query isn't run if we don't pass any query vars
    $dummy_query->parse_query( $request );

    // this is the actual manipulation; do whatever you need here
    if ( $dummy_query->is_home() )
        $request['category_name'] = 'news';

    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'alter_the_query' );
```

Comment: Thanks scribu, this is exactly what I was hoping to learn, and straight from the source, too! I'd like to update that Codex entry at some point since it seems a little scattered. I wonder whether it makes sense to include this code snippet you just included as well? Rarst's cautions are also well advised!

Comment: It wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Done: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request and major cleanup http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts. I would appreciate if you might check to make sure I haven't made any blunders.

Comment: Looks pretty good.

Comment: Is there a reference available regarding how to alter the `$request` object? For instance, how can I redirect a Page to `index.php` and only list a specific category there using this method? I imagine I have to `unset()` the `pagename` key, but what else is there?

Comment: @Isaac Lubow: `$request` is an array, not an object. You can see what else is there like so: `print_r( $request )`.

Comment: Well, that returns an SQL query, in my case `SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (wp_posts.ID = '519') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC`. What's the right way to "clear" this (at least the necessary bits) and return all posts in a category, for example? Do the booleans `is_*()` work on the request the same way they do in a template? Are the same booleans available? How can I know which apply to the `$dummy_query?`

Comment: @Isaac Lubow: If $request is an SQL query, you're doing something wrong. Consider asking a separate question.