# How to make the 'request' filter work?

Tags: wp-query, loop

I'm trying to get a Page to display a custom query using the snippet posted [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/alternative-to-query-posts-for-main-loop). The following is in my `functions.php`:

```
function alter_the_query($request) {
    $dummy_query = new WP_Query();  // the query isn't run if we don't pass any query vars
    $dummy_query->parse_query($request);
    // this is the actual manipulation; do whatever you need here
    if($dummy_query->is_page('blog')) $request['category_name'] = 'Blog';
    // and then
    return $request;
}
add_filter('request','alter_the_query');
```

The page called "Blog" has a basic loop inside- so it should be displaying whatever `WP_Query` tells it to. However, it is only displaying the Page content- which should have been ignored.

I can't seem to find a reference that explains the properties of the `$request` object, so I'm not sure what I should do to make this snippet work. Any ideas?

Comment: According to your code, you are trying to display posts that are in the category "Blog", is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function, simply do a `var_dump` of the `$request` object to reveal its properties.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question name to elicit suggestions about how to actually make the function work. But incidentally, what's a safe way to echo the results of the `var_dump`?

Comment: yeah...wasn't sure this was too helpful, but this would be a good step to get started. The var_dump would just allow you to see the props of the object. Just dump it once to see what's in the object. Then work from there. This is more of a troubleshooting step than a full solution.

Comment: If I do `$vardump = var_dump($request);` in the function, echoing `$vardump` on the page yields nothing. How can I check this value?

Comment: `var_dump` just prints to screen, it doesn't return anything. If you wanted to inspect the request inside a variable you'd have to use `var_export` - ie, `$vardump = var_export( $request, true );`