# What is considered a default query for the request filter?

Tags: wp-query, filters, query

As stated in one of the answers in [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/alternative-to-query-posts-for-main-loop/21378#21378) question and in the codex entry for the [`request`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request) filter, said filter gets called only in a default query, such as the main query used for a loop.  My question is, what else is or isn't considered a default query?  Would creating a new `WP_Query` object be considered such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "default" query is the one WordPress does itself, based on the URL and such, automatically.

Any query you create manually, via a new WP_Query or by calling query_posts(), will not use the 'request' filter.

There is only one "default" query, and you cannot trigger it via any code in the template.

Comment: Just needed some clarification.  Thanks for the answer, Otto man.

Answer (score 2):

[`request`](http://docs.iarp.ca/source_code/wordpress/3.3/nav.html?wp-includes/class-wp.php.source.html#l299) is only applied once, by [`parse_request()`](http://docs.iarp.ca/source_code/wordpress/3.3/nav.html?wp-includes/class-wp.php.source.html#l110), a method of the [`WP`](http://docs.iarp.ca/source_code/wordpress/3.3/nav.html?wp-includes/class-wp.php.source.html#l2) class. There is only one reference to this, it is by another method of [`WP`](http://docs.iarp.ca/source_code/wordpress/3.3/nav.html?wp-includes/class-wp.php.source.html#l2), [`main()`](http://docs.iarp.ca/source_code/wordpress/3.3/nav.html?wp-includes/class-wp.php.source.html#l486). [`main()`](http://docs.iarp.ca/source_code/wordpress/3.3/nav.html?wp-includes/class-wp.php.source.html#l486) is referenced one time, by [`wp()`](http://docs.iarp.ca/source_code/wordpress/3.3/nav.html?wp-includes/functions.php.source.html#l1558). [`wp()`](http://docs.iarp.ca/source_code/wordpress/3.3/nav.html?wp-includes/functions.php.source.html#l1558) is referenced in a few different contexts by a number of different functions and files: `wp_trackback.php`, `get_feed()`, `wp-blog-header.php`, `wp_edit_posts_query()`, and `wp_edit_attachments_query()`. So, looking through that, nothing that `WP_Query calls is listed.

Short answer: I'd say no, it does not call `request`.

All that said, my work is based on working backwards with phpxref (hence the links), so I may have missed something, or it may have missed something. A better way to ask your question might be to ask on what you're trying to do, not on your implementation of it.

Just a note: `main()` does call `query_posts()`, which (I think) does the default query and such, but an instance of WP_Query alone shouldn't be enough to trigger this from what I've seen.