# Possible to get feed to return latest updated posts rather than latest published?

Tags: feed

Currently the RSS feed of my WordPress blog gives me the latest published posts. Is it possible to change this so that it returns the ones that are latest updated instead? So that the latest published are still in the feed, but if I update an old post it would pop up in a feed reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (not tested) add to your functions.php of active Theme

```
function wpse49312_alter_the_query( $request ) {
    $dummy_query = new WP_Query();
    $dummy_query->parse_query( $request );

    if ( $dummy_query->is_feed() )
        $request['orderby'] = 'modified';

    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpse49312_alter_the_query' );
```

From [Alternative to query_posts for main loop?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/alternative-to-query-posts-for-main-loop/21378#21378)

Comment: Tested. Works fine :)

Comment: Cool! Will test it out on my blog. Is there any special meaning to `wpse49312`?

Comment: Added it to my functions.php file now, but doesn't seem to change the order of the feed? As far as I can see anyways... :/

Comment: Actually, seems like it does!